# 'NOT GREATER THAN' condition Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table with columns `userid` and `createdon` where `createdon` column has `DATE` datatype.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID                      UserId                         CreatedOn
1                         65                           2013-06-13 
2                         54                           2013-07-03
3                         34                           2013-08-23
4                         65                           2013-09-13 
5                         89                           2013-09-13
```

Now I want the userids where **last** createdon was before 2013-09-08. The correct answer will be userids 54,34

Using

```
select userid from table  where createdon <'2013-09-08'
```

returns 65,54,34 and usind

```
select userid from table where userid notin (select userid from table where createdon > '2013-09-07')
```

takes a lot of time.

How to get the rows where last createdon  < 2013-09-08

Comment: why are you using subquery for the same table

Comment: 65,54,34 is the correct output.check the date.2013-06-13,2013-07-03,2013-08-23 are less than 2013-09-08.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT UserID, MAX(CreatedOn) CreatedOn
  FROM table1
 GROUP BY UserId
HAVING CreatedOn < '2013-09-08'
```

Output:

```
| USERID |                     CREATEDON |
|--------|-------------------------------|
|     34 | August, 23 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
|     54 |   July, 03 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ec9a4/1)** demo

Comment: this worked. can you explain the logic behind this ?

Comment: I had no idea that SQLFiddle existed. I'd've upvoted you even if your answer was wrong.

Comment: @AkshatGoel First you get last `CreatedOn` per UserId by applying `MAX()` aggregate function and `GROUP BY` then you limit the resultset by getting only rows that have `createon` from the first step less than '2013-09-08' by using `HAVING` clause which exists specifically to apply filtering conditions on aggregated resultset

Comment: @AkshatGoel You're more than welcome. I'm glad I could help :)

Comment: Brilliant answer, nice and performant for my use case. 100,000 rows queried, 77.2ms response time.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Your expectation is wrong. The first row of the table you posted would meet your criteria (`'2013-06-'13' < '2013-09-08'`). So a resultset with `65,54,34` is as expected.</strike>

Misunderstood the question.

What you want is:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
       UserId
    FROM
       tbl outerTbl
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT *
         FROM tbl innerTbl
         WHERE
             outerTbl.UserId = innerTbl.UserId
             AND innerTbl.createdOn >= '2013-09-08'
    )
```

Comment: Yes according to the query i have wriiten this is the correct resultset but my expected resultset ins 54,34 as i want rows with last createdon <2013-09-08. How to write a query for that?

Comment: So you want where where no users having createdOn after that date appear, even if they have them before that date? I'll edit to show this.

Comment: Yeah, @peterm's answer is better.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `STR_TO_DATE()` function

```
SELECT userid FROM table  
WHERE createdon <= STR_TO_DATE('2013-09-08', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is correct, but probably you are not using proper data type for `createdon` column. Check that it works as expected in this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9bd89/1):

```
SELECT userid
FROM mytable
WHERE createdon < '2013-09-08'
```